# JScrollPane doesn't get added yet there are no errors

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have tried so many different methods on stackoverflow but non of them seem to work. Here is a more zoomed in part of my code I am working on:

```
    //add text fields
    String file = "/Applications/Console/v7/latest.log";

    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setBounds(250, 25, 400, 350);

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while(line != null){
      area.append(line + "\n");
      line = in.readLine();
    }
    frame.add(area);
```

This part of the code works perfectly fine and displays the text file in a JTextArea on the correct part of the screen. Issue is I need to add a scrollbar for both vertical and horizontal axis. I've tried to do things such as:

```
    //add text fields
    String file = "/Applications/Console/v7/latest.log";

    JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
    area.setBounds(250, 25, 400, 350);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(area);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    frame.add(scrollPane);

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line = in.readLine();
    while(line != null){
      area.append(line + "\n");
      line = in.readLine();
    }
    frame.add(area);
```

But they still don't seem to work. I have tried many things that also look similar to the code above. I have a feeling it is a bigger issue to do with my class in general, but since it is pretty big, here it is in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/eGdqC36D

Thanks so everyone in advance!

Comment: My guess is, you're using a `null` layout on the frame so the `JScrollPane` is been sized to `0x0`. Suggestion, don't use `null` layouts

Comment: Adding the area to the frame will remove it from the `JScrollPane`. You should also have a look at the `JTextArea#read` method

Comment: I set the JScrollPane size, but now there is no actual button to scroll with, there is just a blank bar.. her is how I resized the Pane though: `scrollPane.setBounds(250, 25, 20, 350);`

Comment: You miss understand the mechanism of how the component hierarchy works, you don't want to add the text area to the frame, you want to wrap the scrollpane around it (which you have done) and add the scroll pane to the frame, the scrollpane then will decide (with the help of the layout manager) which the viewable area will be and with, it will manage the scrollbars based on the required size of the view it contains

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish I could upvote you. If you write an answer I'll upvote it and save it as the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) and [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), you don't want to add the text area to the frame, you want to wrap the scrollpane around it (which you have done) and add the scroll pane to the frame, the scrollpane will then decide (with the help of the layout manager) what size the viewable area will be and with it, will manage the scrollbars based on the required size of the view it contains

[image: ScrollPane]

Comment: Would any one like to point out the reason for the downvote? In what ways does it not answer the ops question? In what ways could it be improved? Apparently we're not suppose to try and help people. Since you've chosen not to downvote the question or the the other answers I can only assume you're been an ass